# Converter java.time.Ser para java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java

Olá.,

Estou lendo a apostila da Caelum sobre [java testes jsf web services design patterns](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-jsf-web-services-design-patterns/trabalhando-com-xml/#4-5-exercicios-lendo-o-xml).

O problema é que não consigo ler a data(eu substitui o `Calendar` pelo `LocalDate` na classe `Negociacao`) por ter essas `tags`(`byte` e `int`) que aparecem quando gero o xml.

E dá esse erro:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot convert type java.time.Ser to type java.time.LocalDate
```

Tentei ler como mostra esse [site](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/axonframework/TUMYBYBcdMc/mkSASIWtAlYJ), mas dá esse erro:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0 : Text '' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Esse é o xml:

```
<negociacao>
    <preco>42.3</preco>
    <quantidade>100</quantidade>
    <data resolves-to=\"java.time.Ser\">
        <byte>3</byte>
        <int>2015</int>
        <byte>11</byte>
        <byte>8</byte>
    </data>
</negociacao>
```

Essa é a classe que lê para ler o xml:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;

import br.com.caelum.argentum.modelo.Negociacao;
import br.com.caelum.argentum.util.LocalDateConverter;

public class LeitorXML {

    public List<Negociacao> carrega(InputStream inputStream){

        if(inputStream == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("a lista esta vazia");
        }

        LocalDateConverter conv = new LocalDateConverter();
        XStream stream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        stream.registerConverter(conv);
        stream.alias("negociacao", Negociacao.class);
        return (List<Negociacao>) stream.fromXML(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Essa é o método da classe `LeitorXMLTest`:

```
@Test
public void carregaXmlComUmaNegociacaoEmListaUnitaria() {
    String xmlDeTeste = "<list>" +
              "<negociacao>" +
                  "<preco>43.5</preco>" +
                  "<quantidade>1000</quantidade>" +
                  "<data resolves-to=\"java.time.Ser\">" +
                      "<byte>3</byte>" +
                      "<int>2015</int>" +
                      "<byte>11</byte>" +
                      "<byte>8</byte>" +
                  "</data>" +
                  "</negociacao>" +
              "</list>";

    LeitorXML leitor = new LeitorXML();
    InputStream xml = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlDeTeste.getBytes());

    List<Negociacao> negociacoes = leitor.carrega(xml);

    for (Negociacao negociacao : negociacoes) {
        System.out.println(negociacao.getData());
    }

    assertEquals(1, negociacoes.size());
    assertEquals(43.5, negociacoes.get(0).getPreco(), 0.00001);
    assertEquals(1000, negociacoes.get(0).getQuantidade(), 0.00001);
}
```

Comment: Parece que o código do *converter* que você pegou naquele fórum simplesmente não vai funcionar porque ele tenta fazer o parse diretamente de uma `String`. Você precisaria de um *converter*mais complexo para lidar com esse caso, mas infelizmente não tenho tempo de entrar nessa questão. Porém, uma alternativa seria simplesmente representar a data usando um formato textual, como `2015-12-30` e criar um converter para trabalhar sempre nesse formato.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o utluiz falou no comentário, eu teria que representar a data em formato textual e assim fiz.

Mudei a classe `Negociacao`, no lugar de `LocalDate` outra classe que tem uma `String`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Data {

    private String datastr;

    public Data(LocalDate data){
        this.datastr = data.toString();
    }

    public Data(String datastr){
        this.datastr = datastr;
    }

    public LocalDate getData() {
        return LocalDate.parse(datastr);
    }

    public String getDatastr() {
        return datastr;
    }

}
```

Fiz outro `Converter`, com base na resposta dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086757/how-to-unmarshal-map-using-xstream):

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter {


    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

        AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) source;

        for(Object obj : map.entrySet()){
            Entry entry = (Entry) obj;

            writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
           writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
           writer.endNode();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        reader.moveDown();
        Data data = new Data(reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();

        return data;
    }
}
```

E o `xml` ficou assim:

```
<negociacao>
    <preco>42.3</preco>
    <quantidade>100</quantidade>
    <data>
        <datastr>2015-11-12</datastr>
    </data>
</negociacao>
```

Demorou, mas consegui fazer.